# ReferenceError: client isn't defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just started building new bot and whenever i try to use node . in the terminal I get error like this;

```
ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Balkanski\Desktop\Bot discord\index.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Here is my whole code, i don't know where the problem could be;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '+';

const fs = require('fs');

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.command.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot is turned on');
}),

client.log('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase
    
    if(command === 'bok'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
})      

client.login('token');
```

Comment: can i see all of codes?

Comment: The error is not in the portion of code that you have posted.

Comment: If you run just that posted code do you get that error?

Comment: I posted whole code now, chek it

Comment: @evolutionxbox if I run just that code that is showed at first I still get the error

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact error message? It should throw an error for the `Client` on line 18 instead.

Comment: @GuyIncognito yes, I am sure

Comment: using Capital C in client? 
`Client.once`
The error seems different

Comment: @AmirSaleem I tried using c and C in `client.once` but i still get same error

Comment: console.log(client) after const client = new Discord.Client();
and check what you are getting

Comment: @AmirSaleem I am still geting the same error

Comment: The error occurs in line 9, which is this one: `client.command = new Discord.Collection();`.

Comment: But you defined client before this so idk where the problem is.

Comment: yes it should not say "client is not defined", client may be undefined but cannot be "not defined". That is impossible. Are you sure you are running this same file?

Comment: @AmirSaleem I am sure

Comment: @AmirSaleem I tried and I got this new error

Comment: but it is too long to post in comments

Comment: discord.js is correct acc. to the documentation, so that is not an issue.

Comment: remove everything, just run const Discord = require('discord.js');

Comment: i tried again and i got new error, it is too long to post whole in comment so I will post the title `TypeError: client.log is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Balkanski\Desktop\Bot discord\index.js:22:8)`

Comment: how come there is an error at line 22 when your file contains only 1 line which is const Discord = require('discord.js');

Comment: Now it says it is typing error, but I don't see where I miss spelled

Comment: which node version are you using? 
check by typing `node -v` in your terminal

Comment: @AmirSaleem v14.15.4

Comment: What do you get when you remove everything and keep just the first line which is `const Discord = require('discord.js');` ?

Comment: i get `TypeError: client.log is not a function     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Balkanski\Desktop\Bot discord\index.js:22:8)`

Comment: remove everything from the file, just keep the first line, client.log is not there in your file, even your file has only 1 line. How come there is an error at line 22. 
make sure to quit from terminal and re-run the file using node .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to reinstall `discord.js` and try this code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '+';

const fs = require('fs');

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.command.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot is turned on');
}),

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase
    
    if(command === 'bok'){
        client.command.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
})      

client.login('token');
```